# WP: Override/update the_content from database with the publicly echo the_content

Tags: hooks, the-content

I have many hooks that apply to the_content (post content) so I want to override the database with that final version of the_content (the one that loads publicly to the user), so I get rid of all the hooks (for example I have many "look and replace" string-a for string-b). I am not certain how to proceed with this, and I really need to make it work because of performing issues. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's probably better to just use a caching mechanism (e.g. a cache plugin). That way, if you want to make any change in the future, that can be easily done without a lot of changes on the database.

Comment: I need to do this only once! to get rid of the hooks that I don´t expect to use again, even for new posts